# Help with height map cropping?

Tags: modeling, displacement, height-map

I'm trying to apply an entire height map to one plane, but it never appears with the full map, just a portion of it. When applied to a much larger plane, it repeats the still incorrect texture. Can anyone help?[image: unscaled plane][image: height map applied to a scale 20 plane with repeating incorrect textures][image: the original height map]

Comment: In the modifier change Coordinates from Local to UV?

Answer (score 0):

In the *Displace* modifier, switch *Coordinates* from *Local* to *UV*, if the unwrap is not correct just unwrap again:

[image]